# Adding Object to a List Of Objects causes all Fields to be null

Tags: c#

i have this class of managament who have list of employe:

```
public static  List<Employee>  EmployeeList = new List<Employee>();
```

the Employee class is this :

```
     public  string firstName { get; set; }
    public  string lastName { get; set; }
    public  string ID { get; set; }
    public Employee(TextBox id, TextBox firstn, TextBox lastn)
    {
        id.Text = this.ID;
        firstn.Text = this.firstName;
        lastn.Text = this.lastName; 
    }
```

i want to add it in another class but when i add it all the fields are null how can i change it ? here is the code were i add the new employee :

```
Mangament.EmployeeList.Append(new Employee(firstNameTextBox,lastNameTextBox,IDTextBox));
```

Big Thanks for helpers

Comment: check your constructor - you are assigning to your inputs values of your properties...

Comment: Also, your `Employee` class shouldn't know anything about text box controls, just pass in the actual string values.

Comment: public properties shouold be named using PascalCase

Comment: Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

As `demo` pointed out, you've got your assignments the wrong way round:

```
    id.Text = this.ID;
    firstn.Text = this.firstName;
    lastn.Text = this.lastName;
```

You've taken the new employee's ID (`null`) and assigned it to the textbox text (blanking the textbox, not storing the thing written in the textbox into the property)

Consider

```
public  string FirstName { get; set; }
public  string LastName { get; set; }
public  string ID { get; set; }
public Employee(string id, string firstn, string lastn)
{
    ID = id;
    FirstName = firstn;
    LastName = lastn; 
}
```

And call it like:

```
Mangament.EmployeeList.Append(
  new Employee(
    firstNameTextBox.Text, 
    lastNameTextBox.Text, 
    IDTextBox.Text
  )
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the very helpfull answer  Hope god bless you